# How can I reverse a corrupted text from a website?

Tags: unicode

so I have this website: http://www.oocities.org/yukaritoto/news/news.htm

[image]

As you can see, most of the text has been corrupted for whatever reason. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: I wonder if its a concequence of the backup process and the codepage....  its also very oddly cropped to one side on my browser

Comment: Or it could be the result of a hack. I would start by restoring a backup, see if that works.

Comment: Also, what does the HTML source code say? Is it corrupted there as well? Do you use a database? Is it corrupted there?

Comment: Was the corrupted text written in Chinese? It seems that only headers (which seem to be "latinised" by most of the Asian websites IMHO) and e-mail-adresses survived. If so, I'd say that it most certainly is an issue with the encoding (UTF instead of ISO or whatever floats that boat).

Comment: @all Yes, it is most likely Chinese or Taiwanese (if there's any difference at all). Sadly, it's not my own website, I'd just like to get the information presented there.

Answer (score 2):

The web is well preserved. It looks to me like this in Chrome 61:

[image]

Google Chrome uses **Auto Detect Encoding** that analyzes the content on the page and uses the most suitable encoding.

Comment: It actually worked in chrome, lol. Didn't think of trying that, thanks so much! :))